# Finding the cross product of surface

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis

[image]

I have done part a). I attached it incase it was useful in calculating part b.

For b) I am confused because vector product is usually for vectors.

I tried writing $\sigma=(x,y+rn \cos v ,z+rb \sin v)$

Then calculated the 2 derivatives but I do not get the required answer. Maybe I need to understand what the vector should be first.

Comment: Because $\sigma$ is vector-valued, it's partial derivatives are also vector-valued.  (By writing $\gamma(s) = (x, y, z)$, perhaps you've lost the dependence on $s$...? Note also that the normal and binormal vectors also depend on $s$. Rather than writing $\gamma$ in components, it's probably easier to work with the Frenet frame of $\gamma$ in Newton notation: $\mathbf{t} = \gamma'(s)$, etc.)

Comment: I had $\sigma_s=\gamma_s+rn_scosv+rb_ssinv$ and $\sigma_v=-rnsinv+rbcosv$

Comment: Those are correct. :) Perhaps use the Frenet equations to express $\sigma_{s}$ as a linear combination of $\mathbf{t}$, $\mathbf{n}$, and $\mathbf{b}$, then compute the cross product using bilinearity (i.e., the distributive law).

Comment: So I write the derivatives as (t,n,b) but what about $\gamma_s$ I am confused what to do with that.

Comment: Note that $\gamma_{s} = \gamma' = \mathbf{t}$.

Comment: Got it thanks..

Comment: Next part says show the Gaussian curvature is $K=\frac{-k \cos v}{r(1-r \kappa \cos v)}$ Should I calculate the first and second fundamental forms? But I got some nasty looking expression.

Comment: You can use part (a) to compute $K$. :)

Comment: I get $N_s = 0$ though?

Comment: I haven't done the calculation, but on geometric grounds $N_{s} = 0$ everywhere can't be right. Have you tried the calculation for an ordinary torus...?

Comment: Well the norm of $\sigma_s \times \sigma_v = r(1-rkcosv)$. So $N=(0,-cosv,-sinv)$?

Comment: Not quite: $N = -(\sin v) \mathbf{b} - (\cos v) \mathbf{n}$.

Comment: I put it into coordinates $(t,n,b)$

Comment: Doing so washes out the dependence of the Frenet frame on $s$. If it's not clear why (or why this matters), write out what happens for a circle in a plane. ;)

Comment: I did that for the cross product and got the right answer (was that lucky)?

Comment: The Frenet frame behaves the same as the standard basis with respect to the cross product, so "lucky" may not be the right word. If you found an ordered triple, then reinterpreted it using the formula you were given for $\sigma_{s} \times \sigma_{v}$, however, it would be accurate to say you made a pair of mutually-canceling mistakes. :)

Comment: Could you please explain how I take the cross product?
I have $N_s= \kappa \cos v\ t+\tau \sin v\ n - \tau \cos v\ b, N_v=  \sin v\ n -\cos v\ b$.


Putting them into coords I get $(0,\kappa \cos^2 v, \kappa \sin v \cos v)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}\newcommand{\Tgt}{\Vec{t}}\newcommand{\Nml}{\Vec{n}}\newcommand{\Bin}{\Vec{b}}\newcommand{\NML}{\Vec{N}}$Since $\gamma$ is a unit-speed parametrization, $\gamma'(s) = \Tgt$. The Frenet-Serret equations read
\begin{alignat*}{3}
  \Tgt_{s} &=              &&\quad\kappa \Nml, && \\
  \Nml_{s} &= -\kappa \Tgt &&                 &&+ \tau \Bin, \\
  \Bin_{s} &=              &&-\tau \Nml.      &&
\end{alignat*}
By definition,
$$
\sigma(s, v) = \gamma(s) + r(\Nml \cos v + \Bin \sin v),
$$
so the Frenet-Serret equations give
\begin{align*}
  \sigma_{v} &= r(-\Nml\sin v + \Bin\cos v), \\
  \sigma_{s} &= \Tgt + r(\Nml_{s}\cos v + \Bin_{s}\sin v) \\
  &= \Tgt + r(-\Tgt\kappa\cos v + \Bin\tau\cos v - \Nml\tau\sin v) \\
  &= \Tgt(1 - r\kappa\cos v) + \tau\sigma_{v}.
\end{align*}
Since $\Tgt \times \Nml = \Bin$, $\Nml \times \Bin = \Tgt$, and $\Bin \times \Tgt = \Nml$,
\begin{align*}
  \sigma_{s} \times \sigma_{v}
  &= \bigl[\Tgt(1 - r\kappa\cos v) + \tau\sigma_{v}\bigr] \times \sigma_{v}
  = \Tgt(1 - r\kappa\cos v) \times \sigma_{v} \\
  &= \Tgt(1 - r\kappa\cos v) \times r(-\Nml\sin v + \Bin\cos v) \\
  &= r(1 - r\kappa\cos v)(-\Bin\sin v - \Nml\cos v).
\end{align*}
As in the comments, $\NML = -\Bin\sin v - \Nml\cos v$ is a unit normal field to your surface, and
$$
\|\sigma_{s} \times \sigma_{v}\| = r(1 - r\kappa\cos v).
$$

Now,
\begin{align*}
  \NML_{v} &= -\Bin\cos v + \Nml\sin v, \\
  \NML_{s} &= \Nml\tau\sin v - (-\kappa\Tgt + \tau\Bin)\cos v
  = \Tgt\kappa\cos v + \tau\NML_{v}, \\
  \NML_{s} \times \NML_{v}
  &= \Tgt\kappa\cos v \times (-\Bin\cos v + \Nml\sin v) \\
  &= \kappa\cos v(\Nml\cos v + \Bin\sin v) = K\, \sigma_{s} \times \sigma_{v},
\end{align*}
from which you can extract the Gaussian curvature $K$.

Comment: Shouldn't $N_s=k \cos v\ t+...$?

Comment: Yes, thanks; fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.